# Hive split function get number of elements

Tags: hive, hiveql

I would like to know if Hive has the option to get number of elements from a String, for example `david.Udert`. I tried this `split(type,'\\.')[2][3]`
and this  `split(type,'\\.')[2:3]` and it doesn't work,
Is there any option to do something like this to get the two words together?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a legitimate description. Did you get an error? Is the query stuck? Did the hive-server2 service crashed? Is your computer on fire?

Comment: What is your actual desired result?

Answer (score 1):

- Array indexes starts with `0`

  ```
  with t as (select 'Now.I.heard.you.know.that.secret.chord' as mycol)

  select  split(t.mycol,'\\.')    as arr
     ,split(t.mycol,'\\.')[0] as arr_1st_element
     ,split(t.mycol,'\\.')[1] as arr_2nd_element
     ,split(t.mycol,'\\.')[2] as arr_3nd_element

  from    t
  ;
  ```

  ---

  ```
  +----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
  |                           arr                            | arr_1st_element | arr_2nd_element | arr_3nd_element |
  +----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
  | ["Now","I","heard","you","know","that","secret","chord"] | Now             | I               | heard           |
  +----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
  ```
- Array slicing is not supported, at least for now. If you want to slice, do it before the split

  ```
  with t as (select 'Now.I.heard.you.know.that.secret.chord' as mycol)

  select  split(substring_index(substring_index(t.mycol,'.',7),'.',-3),'\\.')     as slice_option_1
     ,split(regexp_extract(t.mycol,'(.*?\\.){4}((\\.?[^.]*){0,3})',2),'\\.')  as slice_option_2

  from    t
  ;
  ```

  ---

  ```
  +--------------------------+--------------------------+
  |      slice_option_1      |      slice_option_2      |
  +--------------------------+--------------------------+
  | ["know","that","secret"] | ["know","that","secret"] |
  +--------------------------+--------------------------+
  ```